# Restrict framework from adding optional tags in SOAP xml message in c# NetCore

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, .net-core, xmlserializer

I am working on a REST webapi that consumes a SOAP WS to query for invoices information. I am using SoapUI for testing and I get the correct information. But from my webapi when calling the autogenerated method the request includes all the optional attributes with a default value.

I tried many things and the only thing that worked was to delete all the optional attributes from the autogenerated method which proved the default values are the problem but I might need them if I want to add them as filters to get a specific invoice from another call.
I also tryed adding a boolean property for each optional with "propertyNameSpecified" as mentioned here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer?view=netframework-4.8 but the information is there even though this properties are all false.

here is the WSDL for the WS: https://fwshomo.afip.gov.ar/wsfecred/FECredService?wsdl
and the method is consultarComprobantes that gets an object of type: consultarComprobantesRequest. I can provide code but all this is autogenerated with visual studio's added service, please let me know if you need it anyway.

Result is an empty array when I know there is an invoice (i generated it) and can see it with SoapUI with the request without optional parameters (or correct ones to get to this specific invoice)

Comment: After reading your issue, I still could not understand what you want to express. Simply speaking, you could get the right response by sending request with SOAPUI while calling the service with the client proxy class can not?

Comment: Correct. With SoapUI I only send the xml tags I must. Calling the autogenerated class all "optional" tags are completed with default values and thus the request is sent with filters thus the answer is not correct. I also tryed making all other members nullable and set to null but are also sent with null and the response is a format error for null fields in the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this modifying the proxy class by eliminating all optional members. Its not ideal for if I re-generate the proxy class the solution will no longer work but as long as I don't do that it will be ok.
Whenever I need to send an optional member in the message I simply generate a new class that inherits from the one with only the optional parameters and define whichever optional member I need in the new class.
The proxy method works with the instance of the new class with no problem because of it's inheritance, so no convertion is needed.